# Forcing "char" to be "unsigned char" when compiling with xcodes LLVM compiler

Tags: xcode

Is there a compiler flag for the LLVM compiler using Xcode that will handle all "char" types as "unsigned char"?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag you want is `-funsigned-char`

Xcode's settings view also aliases it with `GCC_CHAR_IS_UNSIGNED_CHAR`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I set "-funsigned-char" to the "Build Settings" -> "Other C Flags" and it works as expected.